# When use multiple Regression and is linear Regression legit in this case?

Tags: regression, least-squares, survey

I have some trouble understanding the use of multiple regression.

I made a survey which has 3 variables (simplified): `A, Skill, Money`. The participants made choice wether they want to work with product `A`, have much `Skill` and have much `Money` on a scale from 1 to 5.

```
                A, Skill, Money
Participant 1: (4,     5,     4)
Participant 2: (2,     3,     3)
Participant 3: (1,     2,     3)
```

etc.

Is it legit to make a OLS `A = coeff * Skill` to see if there is a correlation between those two variables? Or do I have to take account of `Money` as well?

How can one interpret the coefficients of the multiple regression (MLS) `A = coeff_1 * Skill + coeff_2 * Money`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regression of `A` on one of the variables (e.g., Skill) yields a coefficient that describes an association between the two variables. For example, if your coefficient estimate is .2, then for two individuals that differ on skill by 1, you would expect to see them differ on `A` by .2. The doesn't describe a causal relationship between skill and `A`, just an association (the same as correlation). You might be able to predict with some accuracy someone's value of `A` from their value of Skill.

Including the other variable in the regression serves to isolate the effect of one variable from the effect of the other. For example, if in your regression of `A` on Skill and Money you get a coefficient of .05 for Skill and .2 for Money, you can say that two individuals with the same value of money but who differ in Skill by 1 point are expected to differ on `A` by .05. (This assumes the coefficient for skill is the same at every level of Money, which is an assumption you don't have to make if you include an interaction between Skill and Money in your model). Including both variables in the model allows you to examine the "partial" or "unique" effect of each variable: the effect of one variable holding constant the other variable. Note, again, that the effects are merely associations and don't describe causal phenomena like mechanisms.

The choice of whether to include both variables in a regression depends on the question you want to answer. Do you want the marginal association between the the variables and the outcome (i.e., if you only had either Skill or Money and wanted to know someone's expected value of `A`), or do you want the partial or joint association between Skill and Money and `A` (i.e., if you had both and wanted to know someone's expected value of `A`, or if you wanted to know the association between Skill and `A` that is not due to Money).

I personally doubt the usefulness of partial associations that are not causal, but they can be useful in taking the first step to understand your phenomenon (e.g., why is Money associated with `A` after conditioning on Skill?).